# Translating 人は、城であり、かつ、セキュリティホールでもあります。

Tags: translation

> 人は、城であり、かつ、セキュリティホールでもあります

Trying to translate this sentence found in an article about personnel issues at work. For now, I have:

> People can be a fortress or a security risk.

But 城 literally means "castle" and "セキュリティホール" means "security hole". However, it feels odd to me to translate it to say that people are "castles or security holes". I think the author means something like

> "People can be a company's strength or liability."

but I'm not sure if that is close enough to the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This 人は城 is probably a reference to ["人は城、人は石垣、人は堀"](https://www.city.kofu.yamanashi.jp/shingenkou-no-machi/wartactics.html), a wisdom by [Takeda Shingen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takeda_Shingen). This is believed to mean human resources are the most important "infrastructure" of an organization.
- かつ is not "or" but a very explicit "**and** (at the same time)".

So this sentence seems to suggest human resources are the most important (城) to a company, but the most risky/vulnerable (セキュリティホール) thing at the same time. I don't know if there is a catchy paraphrase of this 城 in English, but you might just explain the basic idea.

Comment: "People are a company’s most valuable asset and also its riskiest."

Would this be more accurate?

Comment: @mattmir777 Yes, it seems fine to me.

Comment: @mattmir777 or one might even say "People are both a company's greatest asset, and also its greatest vulnerability."